# Applying a Wordpress patch through a theme's functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to fix the simple issue of Wordpress not allowing "tel:" links in menu items. I found [this patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18469/formatting.php.patch) which fixes the problem, but I have to edit the core file which is not ideal. Any WP masters out there who know of a way to add a protocol to this array via a theme's functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Hotfix plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix/

It basically does this by locating function and overriding it. In your case, try overriding "wp_allowed_protocols". (looking at 3.3 code)

Comment: Well, I thought this would override wp_allowed_protocols, but it doesn't seem to work (in my theme's functions.php file): http://pastebin.com/zWdCW1fB

I know there must be a way, but it's my lack of PHP wizardry that's the problem.

Comment: Pastebin says it's a private paste.